# Kivy: Unable to get kivy argument: add_row in MDDataTable to work

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying to add a row each time I have a new data using "add_row" in-built argument in Kivy's MDDataTable. However, I face the error:

```
line 255, in add_datatable self.data_tables.bind(add_row=self.add_row) 
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 429, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind 
KeyError: 'add_row
```

#The argument that I use  can be found in Kivy's documentation:
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/kivymd/latest/kivymd.pdf

```
add_row(self, data: Union[list, tuple])
#Added new row to common table. Argument data is the row data from the list row_data
```

#The following is some snippets of my code

```
class MyMainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_tables = None
        self.slider = None
        self.date_selected = None
        self.txt = "0"
        self.lst = []

    def build(self):
        self.kv = Builder.load_file("main1.kv")
        return self.kv

    def add_datatable(self):
        count = 1
        condition = "Bad"   # MACHINE LEARNING: LOAD IN TOOL'S CONDITION HERE!!
        tool = "Kuglen"
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}, 
                        size_hint=(0.545, 0.57), 
                        check = True, 
                        rows_num = 5, 
                        use_pagination = True,
                        pagination_menu_height = "240dp",
                        column_data=[
                            ("No.", dp(25)),
                            ("Tools",dp(28)),
                            ("Slot Number", dp(26)),
                            ("Condition", dp(26))
                        ],
                        row_data=[
                            (f"{i+1}", tool, "1", condition)
                            for i in range(2)
                        ]
                        )

        if condition == "Bad":  
            print("Bad tool")
            tool_img = "Capture.png"   
            pop = Popup(title="Faulty tool: "+ tool + " detected", auto_dismiss=True, content=Image(source=tool_img),
                size_hint=(None,None), size=(445,475))
            pop.open()


        self.data_tables.bind(on_check_press=self.check_press) 
        self.data_tables.bind(on_row_press=self.row_press)   
        self.data_tables.bind(add_row=self.add_row)            ##The part that I am having problems with               
        self.root.ids.data_scr.ids.data_layout.add_widget(self.data_tables)

    def change_screen(self, screen: str):
        self.root.current = screen

    def check_press(self, instance_table, current_row): 
        print(instance_table, current_row)

    def row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row): 
        print(instance_table, instance_row)

    def add_row(self, row_data):                      ####The part that I am having problems with
        row_data = [("1", "Mushroom", "3", "Bad")]
        print(row_data)
```

Would greatly appreciate any help given.

Comment: You can bind to a property or an event, but I think `add_row` is actually a method, so you cannot bind to it. Perhaps you should extend the `MDDataTable` class and over-ride the `add_row()` method.

Comment: your documentation shows that `DataTable` has only two events `on_check_press`, `on_row_press` and you can't use `add_row` (besides all events have names with prefix `on_`, and `on_add_row` (if it would exist) would run code **after** adding new row to table (by some other functions). `on_add_row=function` means `when something adds row to table then run "function"`. If you want to run code when you get data then you should rather assign event to source of data - something like `source_of_data.bind(on_new_data=add_row)`

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, by binding the new row to source_of_data, how does that input the data into the datatable? I thought that you have to bind the new row to the datatable to update the row?

Comment: Let's say that instead of adding a row to the table, I would like to update the data using "update_row_data", does it work the same way as what you mentioned for "add_row"?

Comment: Check this answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083706/getting-value-from-class-to-an-other-python/69147088#69147088